# VS Code не подхватывает файлы определений типов для typescript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Использую VS Code.
В корневой папке у меня есть только `package.json`, `tsconfig.json`, `server.js`, `server.ts` 
 (копия `server.js`, только расширение поменял).
Установил зависимости:

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "mongodb": "^3.1.0",
    "socket.io": "^2.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.16.0",
    "@types/mongodb": "^3.1.0",
    "@types/node": "^10.5.1",
    "@types/socket.io": "^1.4.33",
    "tslint": "^5.10.0",
    "typescript": "^2.9.2"
  }
```

В файле сервера есть например такие строчки:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
```

При этом, когда я в js-файле (подчеркиваю - js) навожу курсор на слово `app`, всплывает подсказка:

```
const app : Express
```

А вот в ts-файле подсказка следующая:

```
const app : any
```

Как сделать чтобы VS Code подхватывал файлы определения типов?

P.S. Добавил `tsconfig.json` (не помогло):

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": false,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowJs": true,
    "types" : ["node", "express"]
  }
}
```

Comment: как импортируется экспресс?

Comment: `import express from "express";`

Comment: большое спасибо кэп

Comment: помогло? если нет, возможно нужно добавить tsconfig.json

Comment: что ж, это я виноват - недостаточно понятно изъясняюсь. уточнил/дополнил описание ситуации

Comment: совершенно только нужно убрать     "types" : ["node", "express"] из тсконфига

Comment: эту строчку я добавил т.к. без нее не работало и я пробовал разные варианты. впрочем, с ней тоже не работает. п.с. как же глупо что нельзя писать короткие комментарии

Comment: может залейте проект куда-нибудь (только не яндекс/мэил), я могу проверить работает или нет локально

Comment: О, очень мило с Вашей стороны. Вот добрался до компа: https://github.com/muturgan/testing-tsconfig

Comment: нет проблем, ответил ниже

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как я писал в комментариях, проблема (была) в не-тайпскриптовом импорте модулей:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: К сожалению не работает(
Собственно, если бы дело было в этом, то к чему тогда опция "module": "commonjs".
Импорты не хочу использовать, т.к. очень неудобно будет делать всякие такие штуки const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient или const http = require('http').Server(app).

А по существу пишет такую ошибку:
У модуля "" (именно так - двойные двойные кавычки) path/node_modules/@types/express/index"" нет экспорта по умолчанию

Comment: module commonjs определяет в каком формате модулей тайпскрипт отдаст код на выходе

Comment: require() .. возвращает any, да и как не работает -
на скриншоте же работает :)